# jquery timepicker not working with datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am installing jquery datepicker and timepicker for the first time. Datepicker is working but timepicker is not. Maybe some js conflict?

Datepicker files

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/date.css">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script>
```

Timepicker and using this script https://plugins.jquery.com/jt.timepicker/

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.timepicker.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.timepicker.min.js"></script>
```

Other js on page before closing body tag

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="///js/jquery.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/owl.carousel.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.countTo.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.appear.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom.js"></script>
```

```
    $( function() {
            $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({

                yearRange: '-120:+0', 
                dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true
            });
        } );
        </script>


<script>
$('.timepicker').timepicker();
</script>
```

Is there anyway I can limit datepicker to today() as I am using it for birthdate.

Is there any way to output error in jquery.

And what is wrong with timepicker. Nothing happens when I click the form field.

Answer (score 0):

I changes timepicker js to jquery.timepicker.js

Added maxDate: '0' to limit date to today's date.

Used Console to find jquery errors.